# Core Graphics - draw a gray scale image using array of integers

Tags: ios, core-graphics, cgimage

I am trying to create a UIImage using core graphics.

My wish is to draw an image divided into 4 different gray scale areas/pixels.

....White....Gray.....

.....Gray.....Black...

So using core graphics, i would like to define an array of 4 different `int8_t` which correspond to the desired image:

```
int8_t data[] = {
    255,   122,
    122,     0,
};
```

`255` is white,

`122` is gray,

`0` is black

The best reference for a similar code that i could have found is [here](https://forum.juce.com/t/crashes-with-juce-image-coregraphics-ios-12/29524/32)

This reference refers to an RGB image, so came up with this code per my own common sense (sorry for objective-C french - this is not my reference :)):

```
- (UIImage *)getImageFromGrayScaleArray {
    
    int width = 2;
    int height = 2;
  
    int8_t data[] = {
        255, 122,
        122, 0,
    };

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData (NULL,
                                                               &data[0],
                                                               width * height,
                                                               NULL);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate (width,
                                         height,
                                         [self bitsPerComponent],
                                         [self bitsPerPixel],
                                         width * [self bytesPerPixel],
                                         colorSpaceRef,
                                         kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,
                                         provider,
                                         NULL,
                                         NO,
                                         kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    
    return image;
}


- (int)bitsPerPixel {
    return 8 * [self bytesPerPixel];;
}

- (int)bytesPerPixel {
    return [self bytesPerComponent] * [self componentsPerPixel];
}

- (int)componentsPerPixel {
    return 1;
}

- (int)bytesPerComponent {
    return 1;
}

- (int)bitsPerComponent {
    return 8 * [self bytesPerComponent];
}
```

But... this code gives me this whole black UIImage:

[image]

Can someone please reference me to a point where i can read and understand how to do such a task ? The amount of data about core graphics seem to be quite scarce when trying to do such a task. And the time for all these guesses... forever :)

Comment: Is your goal to create a `2x2` pixel image? With White - Gray as the "top row" and Gray - Black as the "bottom row"?

Comment: Yes it is. I want to create 2x2 pixel uiimage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close...

Gray scale images need **TWO** components per pixel: brightness and alpha.

So, with just a couple changes (see the comments):

```
- (UIImage *)getImageFromGrayScaleArray {
    
    int width = 2;
    int height = 2;
    
    // 1 byte for brightness, 1 byte for alpha
    int8_t data[] = {
        255, 255,
        122, 255,
        122, 255,
        0, 255,
    };
    
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData (NULL,
                                                               &data[0],
                                                               // size is width * height * bytesPerPixel
                                                               width * height * [self bytesPerPixel],
                                                               NULL);
    
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate (width,
                                         height,
                                         [self bitsPerComponent],
                                         [self bitsPerPixel],
                                         width * [self bytesPerPixel],
                                         colorSpaceRef,
                                         // use this
                                         kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big,
                                         // instead of this
                                         //kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,
                                         provider,
                                         NULL,
                                         NO,
                                         kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    
    return image;
}


- (int)bitsPerPixel {
    return 8 * [self bytesPerPixel];;
}

- (int)bytesPerPixel {
    return [self bytesPerComponent] * [self componentsPerPixel];
}

- (int)componentsPerPixel {
    return 2;  // 1 byte for brightness, 1 byte for alpha
}

- (int)bytesPerComponent {
    return 1;
}

- (int)bitsPerComponent {
    return 8 * [self bytesPerComponent];
}
```

---

**Edit** -- I think there's an issue with the memory buffer addressing using the above code. After some testing, I'm getting inconsistent results.

Give it a try with this modified code:

```
@interface TestingViewController : UIViewController
@end
@interface TestingViewController ()
@end
@implementation TestingViewController

// CGDataProviderCreateWithData callback to free the pixel data buffer
void freePixelData(void *info, const void *data, size_t size) {
    free((void *)data);
}

- (UIImage*) getImageFromGrayScaleArray:(BOOL)allBlack {
    
    int8_t grayArray[] = {
        255, 122,
        122, 0,
    };
    
    int8_t blackArray[] = {
        0, 0,
        0, 0,
    };
    
    int width = 2;
    int height = 2;
    
    int imageSizeInPixels = width * height;
    int bytesPerPixel = 2; // 1 byte for brightness, 1 byte for alpha
    unsigned char *pixels = (unsigned char *)malloc(imageSizeInPixels * bytesPerPixel);
    memset(pixels, 255, imageSizeInPixels * bytesPerPixel); // setting alpha values to 255
    
    if (allBlack) {
        for (int i = 0; i < imageSizeInPixels; i++) {
            pixels[i * 2] = blackArray[i]; // writing array of bytes as image brightnesses
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < imageSizeInPixels; i++) {
            pixels[i * 2] = grayArray[i]; // writing array of bytes as image brightnesses
        }
    }
    
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL,
                                                              pixels,
                                                              imageSizeInPixels * bytesPerPixel,
                                                              freePixelData);
    
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width,
                                        height,
                                        8,
                                        8 * bytesPerPixel,
                                        width * bytesPerPixel,
                                        colorSpaceRef,
                                        kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big,
                                        provider,
                                        NULL,
                                        false,
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    
    return image;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemTealColor];
    
    UIImage *img1 = [self getImageFromGrayScaleArray:NO];
    UIImage *img2 = [self getImageFromGrayScaleArray:YES];
    
    UIImageView *v1 = [UIImageView new];
    UIImageView *v2 = [UIImageView new];
    
    v1.image = img1;
    v1.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemYellowColor];
    v2.image = img2;
    v2.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemYellowColor];
    
    v1.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    v2.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    
    v1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:v1];
    v2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:v2];
    
    UILayoutGuide *g = [self.view safeAreaLayoutGuide];
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        
        [v1.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:40.0],
        [v1.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.centerXAnchor],
        [v1.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:200.0],
        [v1.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:v1.widthAnchor],
        
        [v2.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:v1.bottomAnchor constant:40.0],
        [v2.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor],
        [v2.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:v1.widthAnchor],
        [v2.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:v2.widthAnchor],
        
    ]];
}

@end
```

We add two 200x200 image views, and set the top `.image` to the returned `UIImage` using:

```
    int8_t grayArray[] = {
        255, 122,
        122, 0,
    };
```

and the bottom image using:

```
    int8_t blackArray[] = {
        0, 0,
        0, 0,
    };
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: DonMag, Thank you very much for answering this. I find this information very helpful. 

However, when i run it on simulator results do not match what one may expect.

// 1 byte for brightness, 1 byte for alpha
    int8_t data[] = {
        0, 255,
        0, 255,
        0, 255,
        0, 255,
    };

I expect this image to be a whole black image. Even if i stretch it. 
And it's not. Simulator shows something else.

Would love also to know how i can acquire this black magic data my self. 

kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big ...
Two components....

:)

Comment: @Rankito - see the **Edit** to my answer. As to `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big` ... I pulled that from some code I wrote years ago. Can't remember how I got to that :( --- playing around with a few things, this also appears to give the desired result: `kCGImageAlphaLast | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault`

Comment: awesome edit ! Thanks a lot ! This answer should be excepted. Thanks for sharing this data ! 

Last question though :) - How come we have data of 'int8_t' and we malloc data of 'char' ? How these two correspond ?

Comment: I have tested this with:
    int8_t *pixels = (int8_t *)malloc(imageSizeInPixels * bytesPerPixel);

And it seem to work ok. So just wonder why we have used 'char' instead

Comment: @Rankito - I would expect `(int8_t *)` to be equivalent... the use of `(unsigned char *)malloc` was from old code I dug up, and may have had a specific purpose when I originally wrote it. After a quick bit of searching, I'd say *for this specific usage* they are interchangeable and we could also use `uint8_t`... If we look at the header definitions,  we see: `typedef signed char int8_t;`. For this case, `signed / unsigned` doesn't matter. In the end, **consistency** should probably be the deciding factor.